# Create VPN with an Azure VM that is De-allocated each night and uses dynamic DNS

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, azure, windows-server-2012, ddns

I've been on a learning curve with Azure this week and had some great success configuring a Windows 2012 R2 VM for hosting a POC application.  The basics are in place and I've mapped a sub-domain back to the web-app so we can access it via "demo-app.example.com"

The VM is spun up each morning and de-allocated each evening to save costs (currently I'm using free credits from a MSDN account) using automation rules.  The public IP address that the VM picks up as it is re-allocated and started is dynamic so I'm managing the sub domain mapping using dynamic dns with noip.com and this seems to be working well.

I'd now like to lock down the app's availability to just those users with a VPN client but I'm not sure if this is possible given the dynamic public IP address.  All of the documentation I have read on Azure for Managed Resource instances mentions using the IP address to set up a point to site VPN so I expect this would fail the next time the machine is restarted.

We only have one Azure VM that we would like to connect to.

Can anyone say if what I am trying to achieve with the current configuration is possible and if so provide some instructions (or a link to a guide) for achieving what I'm after?

Thanks in Advance,

Paul.

Answer (score 1):

The Public IP will change as it is Dynamic, However the Internal IP will remain same after restarting.

You can create Point to site VPN and use Internal IP to Communicate to server

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps/

All the best 
Let me know if this work :)